# Vagrant multiple VMs with multiple private_network

Tags: vagrant

I want to setup multiple VMs with more then one private_network IP. I use Debian9 as the hostsystem. My Vagrant Version is "Vagrant 2.0.2" from the distribution. The box I use is also a Debian9. I created a Vagrantfile with the following content:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "cluster01"
        config.vm.define "node1" do |node1|
          config.vm.synced_folder "./data/", "/data/"
          config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.21"
          config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.57.21"
                config.vm.hostname = "node1"
  end

        config.vm.define "node2" do |node2|
          config.vm.synced_folder "./data/", "/data/"
          config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.22"
          config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.57.22"
                config.vm.hostname = "node2"
  end
end
```

When I do a "vagrant up" the machines will start. The first machine has the correct settings for the networkcard:

```
 ==> node1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    node1: Adapter 1: nat
    node1: Adapter 2: hostonly
    node1: Adapter 3: hostonly
```

But the second machine has 4 private-networkcards:

```
==> node2: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    node2: Adapter 1: nat
    node2: Adapter 2: hostonly
    node2: Adapter 3: hostonly
    node2: Adapter 4: hostonly
    node2: Adapter 5: hostonly
```

On the second node I have two NICs with IP 192.168.56.22 and two NICs with  IP 192.168.57.22. I could not find any good explanation for this kind of configuration. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems to me, that You are using the global `config` inside the `config.vm.define` clauses - try replacing that with `node1` and `node2` respectively

Comment: Thank you, that's it. You solved my problem :-)